# How to enable an UIButton after entering a valid value

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have this app and a reset button to reset the values that I entered. I'm trying to get the button to be gray as long as I don't enter a valid value.

When the value is valid, it should enable and become touchable...

How can I do this?

I am using this code but it isn't working...

```
//Reset values
- (IBAction)resetPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (didPan==1) {
        resetPressed.enabled = YES;
    } else {
        resetPressed.enabled = NO;
    }
    self.prozent=0;
    didPan=NO;

    //remove drawn intersection line
    [intersectionLine removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"resetPressed");
}
```

Comment: Where you enter the value? UITextField?

Comment: The Value will be given from a touch Gesture ( line ) If i cross the line didPan will be 1 , if not didPan will be 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I did solve the problem after long time of searching.

I found out that the ResetButton must have a Property
it looks like this

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *resetButton;

Then I highlighted the button and unchecked enabled from the control(tried it before but it didn't work)

The I used button.enabled=YES and changed the colour using [resetButton setAlpha:1] for normal and [resetButton setAlpha:0.5] for not activated

Thanks guys for your help!***

Answer (score 2):

To enable the button if it matches your criteria, use **setEnabled:YES**.

E.g.

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
[button setEnabled:YES];
```

An even better way to do this would be to use the dot notated version, like such:

```
button.enabled = YES;
```

Comment: In modern objective-c, dot notation is preferred. i.e. `button.enabled = YES;`

Comment: @Andy Thanks, I'll mention that in the answer if that's ok.

Comment: Well, that is what i've been trying but it's not working. I keep receive reading from the button when I press it :(

Answer (score 1):

In your condition you are using     `if (didPan==1) {` although it would be giving the required result but it is better to use  `if(didPan)`

secondly `resetPresed` is action name not the button or sender, so you should use sender instead of `resetPressed`

and for setting button status use `[sender setEnabled:YES];//OR  sender.enabled=YES;`

so your code would look like this

```
- (IBAction)resetPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

 if (didPan) {
        [sender setEnabled:YES];  //OR sender.enabled=YES;
    } else {
       [sender setEnabled:NO];  // OR sender.enabled=NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: `button.enabled =YES` or `[button setEnabled:YES]`

Comment: `[sender setEnabled:YES];` it is

Comment: You could even shorten to `sender.setEnabled=didPan;`

Comment: @Dave `enabled` is the actual property name . `setEnabled`is the setter   of that property do not mix!! `sender.enabled=didPan;` is right

Comment: yup, typo - that's for catching it.

Comment: OK, but there's a little problem. I'm using the sender to reset values and to be activated when the value that i'm trying to reset is valid. I tried this code  but it isn't working. should I search for another scope to do this?  Thanks everyone for the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are entering a value in a UITextField, you could set the delegate for the text field and write code for enabling/disabling inside `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method of the delegate object. 
i.e; `theButton.enabled = YES/NO`
From your code it looks like you are writing code for disabling the button inside the action of that button itself which won't work if the button is disabled.

Comment: this is also correct, but i does not enable the button while writing the value.

Comment: which is okey. Keep the default state as disabled and after you end the editing , validate the value (textField.text will give the value inside the delegate method) and enable/disable accordingly.

Comment: yes but you have to close the keyboard or resign the first responder another way to check if the value is valid :).

Comment: Actually, i just saw your answer. That will also work just fine. But then it executes extra code every time you type a character.  And eventually you will have to resign first responder anyways or I didn't understand your previous comment correctly. :)

Comment: Another possibility is that value entered can become valid (maybe) even without the user typing entirely what he intended(which might also be valid). Which will lead to the button getting enabled and disabled while the user is typing. Just saying. :D

Comment: :) as i said, your answer is also correct. It just depends on which condition you will validate the input.

Answer (score -1):

if you enter the value for example in a UITextField, then use the delegate of the textfield to determine if the value is correct:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

   if ([textField.text isValid]) { // check if text in textfield is valid

       button.enabled = YES;
   } else  {
       button.enabled = NO;
   }

   return YES;
}
```